# Install pacman on live OS to fix kernel panic caused by package upgrade

Tags: pacman, kernel-panic

I have upgraded the package `libjson-c` to make GIMP work, but it seems like the old version was used by the kernel, which is now unable to boot.

When I choose advanced options in the GRUB menu, both fallback versions (normal + LTS kernel) are not functioning, as I get the same kernel panic message.

The next step I would take, is to boot into a live OS, but I don't know how I would go about reverting the package upgrade.

If the live OS had pacman and I was able to link it with my root partition,

```
pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/package-old_version.pkg.tar.xz
```

would suffice, but I don't know how to achieve that.

In case this is not possible, manually installing the package is also an option, though I don't know in what directory this would be done. Building the package from source and moving it to the correct directory would seem most reasonable in this case. Which directory would this be, though?

I am using Antergos Linux and none of my partitions are encrypted.

Below is an image of the screen I'm getting with the full error message:
[image: Kernel Panic Screenshot]

Comment: The kernel does not depend on the library, but it seems like init does. Take a close look to the message: The library is missing. Have you tried copying /usr/lib/libjson-c.so.3 from the live system into the dead system's file system?

Comment: Hm, I'll try that. I definitely thank you for the tip!

Comment: Do *not* do partial upgrades. From the live medium either do *a full system upgrade* with the `--root` switch, or from a chroot.

Comment: @jasonwryan Could you elaborate? Where do I put thi flag? Last time I used Antergos live, I don't think I remeber pacman being available. But It is currently installing and I'll see

Comment: The steps are [outlined on the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Pacman_crashes_during_an_upgrade).

Comment: Ah, okay; then I was looking in the correct place. I first have to figure out again, though, how to boot from USB on a laptop :S

Comment: Yay, I'm in! Thanks, @jasonwryan, while `--root` was not the answer (`arch-chown` was), it still got me in the right direction. @Hermann unfortunately the library was not included in the live OS, so I could not simply copy.

PS: this has been the 4th time I've bricked and unbricked this machine..

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue, you can do a full system upgrade from Antergos Live.

First mount your root partition (replace `sda1` with the appropriate partition)

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/systemroot
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/systemroot
```

Then you can set that partition as root for the current terminal

```
sudo arch-chroot /mnt/systemroot
```

and do a full upgrade

```
sudo pacman -Syyu
```

<s>I additionally needed to provide `--force`, as I got errors saying some files already existed.</s> *(not advised)*

Comment: **NEVER** run `-Syu` with `--force`: it will break your system. That is why that switch has been deprecated.

Comment: Hm, interesting. It did not break anything and my alternative was going through each conflict. All conflicting packages were from node anyways, so I can fix it easily if something should not be functioning

Comment: The conflicts were because you used npm to install packages, not pacman.

Comment: Yes, is that a bad thing? Why actually are the packages available on pacman, then?

Comment: Yes, it is a bad thing. Pacman is your package manager, installing things behind its back is always a bad idea. If you have to use pip/npm/gem do it in a virtualenv.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip, but all search results for virtualenv get me to Python (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Python/Virtual_environment) do you mean this?

Comment: There is, unsurprisingly, [a wiki page for Node](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Node.js) where all these options are described.